# Creating a new column based on information from two columns in R

Tags: r, replace, na

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| abcdmanagerxyz | crmuix |
| abemployeecxyz | hrmuiz |
| abcdcustomxyz | employee |
| abdresscxyz | floor |
| abcdmanagerxyz | crmuix |
| abemployeecxyz | hrmuiz |
| abcdcustomxyz | employee |
| abdresscxyz | floor |

Using the following code, I managed to create a new column based on column A. But, I have failed to extract information from column B, whenever column A does not have the information. So, I have to use information from Columns A and B in order to have complete information in Column C. [In column B, employee = emp and floor = man]

```
df <- df %>%
  mutate(C = coalesce((str_extract(df$A, 'emp|man')), (str_extract(df$B, 'emp|man'))))
```

Output:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abcdmanagerxyz | crmuix | man |
| abemployeecxyz | hrmuiz | emp |
| abcdcustomxyz | employee | emp |
| abdresscxyz | floor | NA |
| abcdmanagerxyz | crmuix | man |
| abemployeecxyz | hrmuiz | emp |
| abcdcustomxyz | employee | emp |
| abdresscxyz | floor | NA |

Desired Output:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abcdmanagerxyz | crmuix | man |
| abemployeecxyz | hrmuiz | emp |
| abcdcustomxyz | employee | emp |
| abdresscxyz | floor | man |
| abcdmanagerxyz | crmuix | man |
| abemployeecxyz | hrmuiz | emp |
| abcdcustomxyz | employee | emp |
| abdresscxyz | floor | man |

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to use `dplyr::case_when()` and `stringr::str_detect()`:

```
library(tidyverse)
regex = paste(c("emp", "man", "floor"), collapse = "|")
data %>%
  mutate(C = case_when(
    str_detect(A, regex) ~ str_extract(A, regex),
    str_detect(B, regex) ~ str_extract(B, regex),
    TRUE ~ NA_character_
  )) %>%
  # Replace "floor" with "man"
  mutate(C = ifelse(C == "floor", "man", C))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 8 x 3
  A              B        C    
  <chr>          <chr>    <chr>
1 abcdmanagerxyz crmuix   man  
2 abemployeecxyz hrmuiz   emp  
3 abcdcustomxyz  employee emp  
4 abdresscxyz    floor    man  
5 abcdmanagerxyz crmuix   man  
6 abemployeecxyz hrmuiz   emp  
7 abcdcustomxyz  employee emp  
8 abdresscxyz    floor    man
```